# Adding a new entry to struct array overrides all last entries

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm writing a program that reads information from a file, allocates memory for a struct for every line, and fills that struct with information. A pointer to the struct is then placed in a global array.

Every line in the file (except the first one) is in format 'Unsigned Char - Char - Unsigned Char - Char[]'.

My problem is that every time I add a new struct, the Char[] in all the other structs get overwritten.

Say I have the following file:

```
1 10 6 first
2 12 7 second
3 15 6 third
```

When I run my program with that file, and then print the global array it gives something like this output:

```
ID: 1 | FLAGG: 10 | STR_LEN: 6 | MODELL: third
ID: 2 | FLAGG: 12 | STR_LEN: 7 | MODELL: third
ID: 3 | FLAGG: 15 | STR_LEN: 6 | MODELL: third
```

instead of the expected:

```
ID: 1 | FLAGG: 10 | STR_LEN: 6 | MODELL: first
ID: 2 | FLAGG: 12 | STR_LEN: 7 | MODELL: second
ID: 3 | FLAGG: 15 | STR_LEN: 6 | MODELL: third
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 256

struct myStruct* globarlArray[MAX_LENGTH]

struct mySTruct{
    unsigned char ID;
    char FLAGG;
    unsigned char str_len;
    char* modell;
};

int set_variables(struct myStruct* s, unsigned char new_ID, char new_FLAGG, unsigned char new_str_len, char* new_modell){
    s->ID = new_ID;
    s->FLAGG = new_FLAGG;
    s->str_len = new_str_len;
    s->modell = new_modell;
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //Read from file
    ...
    //Initialize structs, add variables to struct, and add struct to global array
    unsigned char ID;
    int ID_INT;
    char FLAGG;
    unsigned char str_len;
    char modell[253];
    char* tempstr;

    for (i = 1; i < lines; i++){
        tempstr = str[i]; //str[1] is first line of into from file, str[2] is second line,...
        Ruter_ID = tempstr[0];
        Ruter_ID_INT = Ruter_ID;
        FLAGG = tempstr[1];
        str_len = tempstr[2]; 
        sprintf(modell, "%s", tempstr+3);
        struct myStruct *line = (struct myStruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
        set_vars(line, ID, FLAGG, str_len, modell);
        globalArray[ID_INT] = line;
    }
    //print array
    for (i = 0; globalArray[i] != NULL; i++){
        printf("ID: %d | FLAGG: %d | str_len: %d | Modell: %s", 
        globalArray[i]->ID, globalArray[i]->FLAGG, globalArray[i]->str_len, 
        globalArray[i]->modell);
    }
    //Some more code
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post real code that compiles

Comment: You only have one char buffer, `char modell[253];` . Your code makes all `s->modell` point to this same buffer.

Comment: Do you understand pointers?

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that every time I add a new struct, the Char[] in all the other structs get overwritten.

That happens since you are using:

```
    set_vars(line, ID, FLAGG, str_len, modell);
```

`modell` is an array. You are storing the pointer to the first element of that array in every instance of `myStruct`.

You need to allocate memory for every instance of `myStruct` and store that pointer<sup>1</sup>.

```
    char* copy = strdup(modell);
    set_vars(line, ID, FLAGG, str_len, copy);
```

You'll then need to make sure that the copy is deallocated.

---

<sup>1</sup> `strdup` is not a standard library function but it can be easily implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Your `modell` array is being used over and over -- the same chunk of memory is being pointed to by each of your structures. You should give each of your structures a copy of the string (perhaps by using `strcpy()` or a related function. (You'll have to worry about freeing the memory of that copy, too, when you free the structure).